# Finding the orientation of a clock face

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am currently writing a computer vision application to read an image of a clock and predict the time that is being shown. Currently it is assuming that the clock always has 12 at the correct position. I am wondering what would be the best method of determening the orientation of the clock. I was considering doing pattern matching on the numbers but quickly realised this would be impractical due to them being rotated.

Comment: I guess image can come from different clock with different typo for numbers?

Comment: You can rotate the image n degrees to have something directly at the top, then try to match and rotate 30 degrees (360/12, to have something else at the top) and repeat until you match. :P Or rotate your pattern to match because it might have better resolution.

Comment: @akhetos yes, it can tho i think if i assume either roman numerals or decimal numbers that will cover most clocks.

Comment: @h4z3 yea i guess thats what i am going to have to do, as i do not see many other ways of doing it. Thanks tho

Comment: Try to find contours looks like oval inside other contour. It's great feature, cause not so much symbol have this property. And with this info you can restore orientation.

Comment: Assuming you can find the locations of the numbers, I would expect `10`, `11` and `12` to have a larger area (more pixels) than `1`, `2`, and `3` (whether in Arabic or Roman numerals). Find where the areas change and you've found where `12` is. Without sample images or something more to go on, I really can't say much more.